# Getting the data back from child to parent element in Vue

Tags: vue.js, parent-child, custom-component

Before last updates I used a custom component to work with sliders. Works perfectly, but after upgrading I got a problem.
This is the wayI use my custom component:

```
<ta-slider2 v-model="stelling1"/>
```

This passes the value to the custom component and received the data back.
This is my custom component

```
<template>
    <div class="mt-3">
        <div><br><br></div>
        <v-slider
                prop="value"
                v-model="interface"
                :value="value"
                :color="color"
                always-dirty
                min="-100"
                max="100"
                thumb-label="always"
        >
            <template v-slot:append>
                <v-icon color="blue">add_circle_outline</v-icon>
            </template>
            <template v-slot:prepend>
                <v-icon color="error">remove_circle_outline</v-icon>
            </template>
        </v-slider>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: "ta-slider2",
        props: {
            value: null
        },
        data() {
            return {

            }
        },

        computed: {
            interface: {
                get() {
                    return this.value
                },
                set(val) {
                    this.$emit('input', val)
                }
            },


            color() {
                if (this.value < 0) return 'red'
                if (this.value > 0) return 'blue'
                return 'red'
            },
        },
    }
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

Worked perfect but now  the line with v-model="interface" gives problems. Googled for hours but can not find a solution. Who can help me out?

Comment: what a error you got in console?

Comment: What does `v-slider` look like?

Comment: V-slider is a vuetify slider component. And in the eslint and console i got the message that interface may not be used it's reserved